# How to clear firebase notification in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi am using FirebaseMessaging in my Flutter application to receive notifications. My application is receiving notification properly and displaying in notification tray when my app is not running.

The problem is:
I received some notification for my application and those are added in notification tray. Then i navigated my application from application icon from launcher. Here i need to clear all the notifications related to my application from notification tray.

Please advice me one this. How to do it for Flutter application.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
 
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Removing All Notifications
    cancelAllNotifications();
}

private void cancelAllNotifications() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i am looking for the solution in Flutter.

Comment: Have you found the solution in Flutter @RaghuMudem?

Comment: @Sujal, Yes there is not direct way from flutter. I have added clear notification code in both android and iOS entry points. Those will clear all the app related notification on launch.